# What does the new full stop / period mean in the RHEL6 ls output?

Tags: redhat, ls

We have scripts looking at the output of `ls -l` output for permission information that have been failing recently on RHEL v6 systems which appear to be showing an extra `.` at the end of the permission entry that didn't used to  be there before:

```
[root@rhel6vm ~]# ls -l
total 44
-rw-------. 1 root root  1399 Aug 17 15:01 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 25485 Aug 17 15:01 install.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  7253 Aug 17 14:59 install.log.syslog
[root@rhel6vm ~]#
          ^
          | up there
```

What does the full stop signify? And what else can appear in it's place?

Comment: `We have scripts looking at the output of ls`, that is generally a [bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Parsing ls is a bad idea.  You would be better off looking at the output of stat or some other tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

info ls shows:

```
  Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
 whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
 applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode
 bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is
 a printing character, then there is such a method.

 GNU `ls' uses a `.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
 security context, but no other alternate access method.

 A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
 marked with a `+' character.
```

Comment: aha - had looked at `man ls' but didn't think of `info ls' - thanks

Answer (score 8):

GNU ls uses a `.` character to indicate a file with an SELinux security context, but no other alternate access method.

A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is marked with a `+` character.